# java implementation : polling a web service

Tags: java, web-services, algorithm, jakarta-ee, webservice-client

Please find below my requirement.

Requirement : Poll a web service. Two crucial parameters of polling max_timeout, polling_interval are configured in properties file. Overall objective is to spend for a time of  overall in obtaining the response. If we get the response with in max_timeout, we can return the response to client. Otherwise we will throw an error saying that the operation is unsuccessful.

Below is the code snippet I have written.

```
int maxTimeOut = 10;
int interval   = 2;

int iterations = maxTimeOut/interval;
boolean success = false;

for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Number of iteration = " + i);
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(interval * 1000);
        System.out.println("Waited for " + interval + " seconds");

        success =  getWSResponse(i);
        System.out.println("CALL" + ((success) ? "SUCCESSFUL" : "FAIL"));

        if(success) break;

    }catch (InterruptedException ie)
    {
        System.out.println(ie.getMessage());
    }
}

//Send the success flag to client
```

Could you correct me if this is the proper implementation of polling. I am little bit concerned that this code assumes that webservice call returns in no time. If this takes 2-3 seconds (usually it does ), then we would be spending more than max_timeout overall for POLLING alone. How could we fix this. Is there any better approach than this.

Comment: `catch (InterruptedException ie)    {    System.out.println(ie.getMessage());     }` ... don't do that. Just rethrow it  `{ throw new RuntimeException(ie) }`

Comment: Thanks artbristol for your suggestion. I will make this code change to throw RTE instead of SOP.

Answer (score 2):

you can combine the use of a `ScheduledExecutorService` with the `HttpURLConnection`-Timeout to poll in a given delay - and abort the task if it takes any longer.

Comment: Thanks light. Could you pass on the sample code/url where this scenario is described properly.  BTW,do you see any issues with the code snippet I have attached (other than the problem I have specified)

Comment: one problem of your code would be interruption. Since you do not propagate the interrupted flag or throw the interrupted exception.

Answer (score 1):

If polling just means that the webservice is up and running, in your poll code you can try to open a connection to the webservice (with connection timeout) .If you are successfully able to connect, this means the webservice is up.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
URL url = new URL("URL");
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection .setConnectTimeout(timeout);//specify the timeout and catch the IOexception
connection.connect();
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you can call the webservice using an executor (see **java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService**) in a task with timeout and can decide accordingly. Sample :

```
// Make the ws work a time-boxed task
            final Future<Boolean> future= executor.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {         
                @Override
                public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                    // get ws result
                       return getWSResponse();
                }
            });
try {
                boolean result = future.get(max_wait_time, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (TimeoutException te) {
throw e;
}
```

Comment: Nrj, we have to actually call a method on web service which returns large xml, which we need to parse it and then we find out whether the response is 'success' or 'inprogress'. This whole thing is abstracted in **getWSResponse** call above. The objective is not to just check about the connectivity.

Comment: is it ok to use that future code in a controller class and not have it locked up?